# Flip a sweep in Revit 2014

Tags: c#, .net, revit-api

I've succesfully created a `Sweep` using a loaded profile. Now I need to flip it along the path. I've tried this statement:

```
sweep.ProfileSymbol.IsFlipped = true
```

But, after the execution, `IsFlipped` is always `false`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more of the code sample available? Perhaps you've moved out of the local range of the variable by the time you query the value of "sweep's" status?

Comment: I query that value after the execution of the statement. The value of IsFlipped property is not so important to me but I need that the sweep will actually be flipped, and it's not.

Comment: Just to check - you're doing all of this within a transaction correct? Also, the statement above will only tell you IF the element is flipped, it won't flip it for you. I think you can probably flip it using methods in the ElementTransformUtils class though.

Comment: Yes this is inside a transaction (otherwise an exception will be thrown). The ElementTransformUtils class doesn't have a flip command. Mirror|Rotate are not the same as flip for non-linear paths

Comment: have you tried just regenerating the document first?